# How can we represent Newton's method in terms of first order differential equations including Jacobian matrix?

Tags: jacobian

To solve a system of nonlinear equations which are equal to zero, ${f_i}(X) = 0\forall i \in 1:m,X = \left[ {{x_1},{x_2}, \cdots ,{x_n}} \right]$, we use Jacobian matrix and Newton algorithm. Hence, at each iteration, updated $X$ can be find by the following equation

${X^{(k + 1)}} = {X^{(k)}} + {J^{ - 1}}\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {{f_i}({X^{(k)}})} \\ 
  {{f_2}({X^{(k)}})} \\ 
   \vdots  \\ 
  {{f_m}({X^{(k)}})} 
\end{array}} \right]k = 0:j$

Where $J = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\frac{{\partial {f_1}({X^k})}}{{\partial {x_1}}}}&{\frac{{\partial {f_1}({X^k})}}{{\partial {x_2}}}}& \cdots &{\frac{{\partial {f_1}({X^k})}}{{\partial {x_n}}}}\\
{\frac{{\partial {f_2}({X^k})}}{{\partial {x_1}}}}&{\frac{{\partial {f_2}({X^k})}}{{\partial {x_2}}}}& \cdots &{\frac{{\partial {f_2}({X^k})}}{{\partial {x_n}}}}\\
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
{\frac{{\partial {f_m}({X^k})}}{{\partial {x_1}}}}&{\frac{{\partial {f_m}({X^k})}}{{\partial {x_2}}}}& \cdots &{\frac{{\partial {f_m}({X^k})}}{{\partial {x_n}}}}
\end{array}} \right]$

The question is how to represent the above in terms of Jacobian matrix and first differential equations of ${f_i}(X)$ or $X$.

Comment: I don't understand, you already wrote the desired answer. Do you mean how to analytically write the inverse? It's useless (except possibly in 1D and 2D), don't bother.

Comment: It is true that the desired answer has written above but my question relates to the previous step, explicitly before identifying optimal $X(k)$.

Comment: I still don't understand. $J$ is the Jacobian matrix, and it is by definition given by first partial derivatives of the $f_i$. So what is your question?

Comment: Let's forget the above. One way to express ${f_i}(x)=0$$\forall {f_i}$ is $\Delta F(X) = J\Delta X $. Now, I want to write the latest in terms of first order differential equation.

Comment: Why? Do you want to devise some kind of "continuous flow" method for solving nonlinear systems? Newton's method is not of this character at all, so you'll want to think differently to find such a thing.

Comment: Thank you. I think you restate my problem in a few words. However, could you explain the assumptions that we could derive $\dot X = f(X)$ from a Newton's method?